# Attach pdf file civicrm_api3

Tags: custom-fields, api, civicrm-entity

i need help, i'm trying to attach through **civicrm_api3('Attach', 'create'..)** a **pdf** file, passed with a rest call as simply text:

```
%PDF-1.3
1 0 obj
<< /Type /Catalog
... ecc
```

.
The attach works, but i thing that during it, the crm's file save function make an escape of some special chars... the results of content of pdf file is:

```
%PDF-1.3
1 0 obj
&lt;&lt; /Type /Catalog
... ecc
```

there is a way to avoid this behavior?

thanks

Comment: I'm trying to find another solution to programmatically attach a file to custom field through API... but for now i haven't found it.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, this is a half-answer.

The HTML encoding is being added because [this line](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/Civi/API/Subscriber/WrapperAdapter.php#L101) is adding default 'wrapper' functions that include adding HTML entities (`CRM_Utils_API_HTMLInputCoder`).

You can fix this by altering the defaults passed into `WrapperAdapter::construct()`, to include `'content'` in the array of `skipFields`. I think you could do this [here](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Utils/API/HTMLInputCoder.php#L69).

Just add a line like

```
'content', // For attachment.create
```

This does work - I tried it.

**However this may not be secure** because I don't know if any of the other APIs use the rather generic 'content' parameter name. If they do, then removing the protection afforded could result in XSS vulnerabilities or other problems.

So the other way to fix it would be rename the API `content` something more unique `attachment_content` - but that would require changing a public API (!)

So another way would be to put in some sort of check that changes the default wrappers for the particular case of `attachment.create`, but I'm not familiar enough with the internal workings of the API system to suggest that patch.

Hmmm.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for answer me! i've resolved in this way:

1. I've created file with pure PHP
2. Then i've used **civicrm_api3('Attach',...)** with 'options.move-file'.

**options.move-file** is used to attach to civicrm_file record the previously created file.

Maybe isn't the best solution, but works!

Thank you!